# Ansible, attempting to get specific regex pattern to work with lineinfile module

Tags: linux, text-processing, regular-expression, ansible

As per my question above:
"Ansible, attempting to get specific regex pattern to work with lineinfile module"

Essentially, I'm trying to get it to work in a single play as opposed to 2 separate plays, and for this a regex is required.  I've tried a few variations that would work with sed, but they don't appear to work here.  Maybe I'm crazy.  Example of what I am trying to do is below:

```
  - name: Change file contents on CentOS and Redhat servers.
    lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/blah/randomfile
    regexp: '^ThisValueHere|^#ThisValueHere'
    line: 'ThisValueHere no'
    when: (ansible_distribution == "CentOS")  or (ansible_distribution == "RedHat")
```

(Yeah yeah, ignore bad yml syntax, it's just fine in the actual playbook)

Basically I want to match lines STARTING WITH: (ThisValueHere, OR, #ThisValueHere), and then replace either of those lines with the line: (ThisValueHere no)

However, I can't seem to get it to work properly, maybe I just really have to brush up on regex stuffs.  In any case, if anyone has any suggestions that would be highly appreciated!

Additionally if there is a link that could be provided to the "keys" to successful ansible regex usage, that would be greatly helpful as well.

Comment: The "keys" tosuccessful ansible regex usage is to understand that is [python regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). You can try with an [online tool](https://regex101.com) using flavor **python**.

Comment: Your example works for me.  Your YAML indenting (or lack of) may be part of the problem.  When my indenting matches yours it doesn't work.  When I indent properly it does.  As for regex, it's Python regex, link requested: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

It works with the `replace` task, `lineinfile` does not provide the [multiline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) python regexp.

`- name: Change file contents on CentOS and Redhat servers.
  replace:
    dest: /etc/blah/randomfile
    regexp: '^(#?ThisValueHere)'
    replace: 'ThisValueHere no'
    when: (ansible_distribution == "CentOS")  or (ansible_distribution == "RedHat")`

Comment: Exactly as @xtrmz has said. You are using the wrong ansible module. From the 'lineinfile' module synopsis, `This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only. See the "replace" module if you want to change multiple, similar lines ... in a file.` https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html